# ¿Como llamar una aplicación externa a través de un comando en Python?

Tags: python

Necesito llamar un ejecutable que esta en el mismo directorio que un *script* [python](/questions/tagged/python) en ejecución. Yo necesito saber como hago para llamarla a través de un comando desde mi *script* con unos parámetros.

En la línea de comando del Windows, hago así:

```
miejecutable -p1 datos
```

De preferencia si hay una forma de ejecutarlo tanto en Python 2 como en 3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Respuesta traducida de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/89243/255257

Utiliza el [módulo sobprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) en stdlib:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["miexecutable", "-p1", "datos"])
```

*edición*

Vale la pena mencionar que `call` te devuelve el código de salida del programa o comando ejecutado, que puedes recoger de la siguiente manera:

```
return_code = subprocess.call(["miprograma.exe", "/parametro"])
```

Otra característica es que puedes realizar la llamada mediante el interprete de comandos del sistema, pasando el parámetro shell=True, así:

```
return_code = subprocess.call("echo Hello World", shell=True)
```

La ventaja de utilizar subprocess versus system es que es más flexible (puedes obtener tanto stdout como stderr, el código de salida "real", mejor manejo de errores, etc.).

os.system es obsoleto, o lo será pronto:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module

Para scripts de una corrida, o soluciones rápidas y sucias, `os.system` es suficiente:

```
os.system("miexecutable -p1 datos")
```

Comment: Tenes toda la razón, Math, ya corregí el ejemplo.

Comment: Creo que podría decir que el `call` también retorna un código indicando suceso o error. Sé que la respuesta de tu enlace no mostra eso y és la acepta, pero se mirar la segunda respuesta de la misma pregunta hay esta información en el item 4. Y creo que és una información muy importante :)

Comment: De nuevo, @Math, gracias, edité la respuesta y añadí información adicional que venía al caso, como recoger el código de salida, y cómo invocar al interprete de comandos.

Comment: Pero ejecutar con subprocess, la ventana desde donde ejecuto el script se bloquea, como se puede hacer en segundo plano y no bloquear la ventana principal, yo ejecuto un script desde una ventana tkinter, pero se bloquea

res = str(pathScripts).format(script)
subprocess.call([res], shell=True)

Answer (score 6):

Parece simple, tienes tu script de la siguiente manera:

```
import os
#Varias líneas debajo
result = os.system('archivo_ejecutable -p1 datos > salida_del_comando.log')
if result == 0:
  print('Parece que todo bien')
else:
  print('Revisar archivo: salida_del_comando.log para tener más detalle')
```

Te explico línea a línea:
En la línea 1, importamos el módulo del sistema operativo.
La línea 2 es un comentario y en la línea 3 es donde tú ya necesitas ejecutar el comando, la función `os.system` nos da una línea del sistema en la cual podemos ejecutar comandos.

La línea 4, guarda el resultado del comando, y en la línea 5 comparamos, si la salida del comando es 0, quiere decir que sistema ejecutó el comando sin problemas, en la línea 6 manejamos en caso de que el sistema haya tenido un error.

Si te fijas en la línea 3 le decimos a la línea del sistema que, todo lo que arroje el comando, lo vacíe en el archivo salida_del_comando.log, para así tener detalle de qué pudo haber fallado.

Espero que te sirva.

**EDIT:**
Olvidaba lo que comentaba @jachguate, que os.system está por ser sustituido en las siguientes versiones de Python, por lo que se recomienda el uso de `subprocess.call`

**EDIT 2:** Si vas a utilizar `subprocess.call` recuerda también agregar el parámetro `shell=True`, quedando tu llamada:

```
subprocess.call('archivo_ejecutable -p1 datos > salida_del_comando.log', shell=True)
#o también:
commandlist = 'archivo_ejecutable -p1 datos > salida_del_comando.log'.split(' ')
subprocess.call(commandlist, shell=True)
```

Para que te evites problemas de qué no puede hallar archivos que dependen del shell/línea del sistema actual en donde estás.

Comment: Ah sí, han casos en que se necesita saber sí el ejecutable he corrido bien o no. Bien observado.

Comment: Para ser correctos, en la línea 3, no se le pide "al sistema operativo" que vacíe la salida, sino al interprete de comandos. No hay forma directa de emular ese comportamiento con una llamada directa al OS sin pasar por el shell, si no es recogiendo nosotros mismos la salida en un stream y posteriormente guardar ese stream a un archivo.

Comment: @jachguate no dije al sistema operativo, dije a la línea del sistema, que es cómo se le llama a las shell en Windows (-:
Y la respuesta es cómo ejecutar un comando, no la teoría de sistemas operativos de cómo funciona un stream o que hace la el módulo os por debajo (-:

Comment: @Omar, gracias por la corrección a tu respuesta. En tu [respuesta original](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/2437/revisions) decía "sistema operativo", pero eso es secundario, no quise dar lecciones de teoría de sistemas operativos, solo quise ayudar a mejorar tu respuesta con la terminología correcta, que insisto que es _interprete de comandos_, o ya de perdida, _shell_.