# Incrustar comandos de windows o .cmd en un script de python

Tags: python, cmd

Hice un file .cmd que ejecuta un programa especifico de windows. Pero el script completo lo escribí en Python. ¿Como incrusto el .cmd o ese código en python?

Comment: ¿Tomas lo que quieres es lanzar un programa o comando desde el script Python? Mírate https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2434/15089. El módulo [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) es posiblemente lo que buscas.

Comment: Un comando desde el script de Python

Answer (score 1):

Para poder ejecutar comandos externos debes usar una de las posibilidades que te ofrece [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). La recomendada es [run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run). Te paso un ejemplo que uso yo, teniendo en cuenta que no se captura la salida.

```
import subprocess
#...
def cmd(commando):
    subprocess.run(commando, shell=True)
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
# Cambiar el título de la ventada de la consola
cmd('TITLE Título de la ventana')
# Ejecutar cmd externo
cmd('myscript.cmd parametro1 parametro2')
```

Al usar `shell=True`se pasan los parametros como texto. Puedes verlo con mas detalle en este artículo de [Chris Griffith](http://www.codecalamity.com/run-subprocess-run/#shell).

Si te interesa revisar lo que devuelve tu código, debes usar [CompletedProcess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess).

```
def cmd(commando):
    resultado = subprocess.run(commando, shell=True)
    # Comprobar resultado, si es diferente de 0 lanza una excepción
    resultado.check_returncode()
```

Nota: CompletedProcess solo está disponible a partir de Python 3.5